# Rails 7 deployment fails using capistrano with SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, deployment, capistrano, sshkit

I am trying to deploy a Rails 7 app to a Vultr VPS for the very first time using Capistrano. I followed **[this guide on GoRails.com](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/22.04#vps).** All goes well up to the final step: deploy the app using Capistrano. My setup is as follows:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Jammy (client and server)
- Ruby 3.2.2 / Rails 7.0.4.2
- rbenv 1.2.0-59-g0704e65
- Bundler version 2.4.10
- capistrano (3.17.2)
- capistrano-bundler (2.1.0)
- capistrano-passenger (0.2.1)
- capistrano-rails (1.6.2)
- capistrano-rbenv (2.2.0)
- net-ssh (7.1.0)
- openssl (default: 3.1.0)

When running `cap production deploy` (*with* `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key` in the ssh server config file) I get this error:

```bash
verify_host_key: :secure is deprecated, use :always
Thread:0x00007f169f27a710 /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: could not settle on host_key algorithm (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
Server host_key preferences: ssh-ed25519
Client host_key preferences: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:inblock (2 levels) in execute'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/net-ssh-7.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:410:in `negotiate': could not settle on host_key algorithm (Net::SSH::Exception)
Server host_key preferences: ssh-ed25519
Client host_key preferences: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512
...
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: could not settle on host_key algorithm
Server host_key preferences: ssh-ed25519
Client host_key preferences: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512
```

And *without* a HostKey variable on the server I get this error:

```bash
verify_host_key: :secure is deprecated, use :always
Thread:0x00007f0d3c68a6c8 /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: fingerprint SHA256:6EF6B30F9E557F948C402C89002C7C8A is unknown for "xx.xx.xx.xx" (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
...
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: fingerprint SHA256:6EF6B30F9E557F948C402C89002C7C8A is unknown for "xx.xx.xx.xx"

Caused by:
Net::SSH::HostKeyUnknown: fingerprint SHA256:6EF6B30F9E557F948C402C89002C7C8A is unknown for "xx.xx.xx.xx"

Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I can do a password-less ssh into the server, no problem, so PubKey authentication appears to work just fine.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Many thanks for any help.

I have tried many suggestions for similar sounding errors posted here and elsewhere, including:

1. deleting known_hosts on the client and adding the server fingerprint to a new known_hosts file.
2. adding PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ed25519 to the server's ssh config file (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952049/sshkitrunnerexecuteerrorexception-while-executing-as-rootservercoauthen))
3. changing all private and public keys on the client and server to use ed25519
4. switching off verify_host_key setting in ssh_options in deploy.rb

Answer (score 1):

> **Host Keys**
> ssh-ed25519 | Require the gem `ed25519`
> *https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh#host-keys*

You need to install two extra dependencies for `ssh-ed25579` support:

```bash
bundle add ed25519 bcrypt_pbkdf
```

*https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh#install*

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for replying!

I tried your suggestion, but got:

`Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xxx.xx: agent could not sign data with requested identity (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)`

I did manage to fix this by adding to ~/.ssh/config this:

`Host *
 IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_ed255190`

However...before doing that I destroyed my old ssh keys and created new ones, so I'm not sure exactly what was causing the error! However, site is now deployed. I will try and remove gems ed25519 and bcrypt_pbkdf to see if I can still deploy. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error when deploy with capistrano to Debian 12 server.

*/usr/local/bundle/gems/net-ssh-7.1.0/lib/net/ssh/verifiers/always.rb:53:in `process_cache_miss': fingerprint SHA256:JHDY3pi7IAYJQP8u5UdSSO/WfOjmqdAijpKLJJH6t0 does not match for "127.20.250.55" (Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch)*

There are 2 problems (in your case):

- your capistrano not support ed25519 (fix this by adding `bundle add ed25519 bcrypt_pbkdf` to your ruby)
- ssh-rsa keys are deprecated and you must use something new. ed25519 is an option.

OR, if you agree with old good rsa:
add this

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

into server`s **/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/enable_rsa_keys.conf**
and use

```
service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different error, but it could help people arriving at this thread.

My error occurred when deploying a Rails 7 app, running on Ruby 3.3.0, with Capistrano 3.11.

```
#<Thread:0x00007f1c21b600c8 /home/jim/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/home/jim/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.5/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': 
Exception while executing as deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: no implicit conversion of nil into String (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
```

The solution was to bump the version of the net-ssh gem as described in this GH issue: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/2146

```
bundle update net-ssh
```

And re-run the deployment.